# How to consume REST web service with ActiveMQ in Mule

Tags: rest, mule, activemq-classic, mule-studio

I have a requirement where I need to expose a REST web service in Mule .. I have the following flow in Mule :-

```
   <flow name="MainService" doc:name="MainService">
        <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8082" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <logger message="RequestLog :- #[message.payloadAs(java.lang.String)]" level="INFO" doc:name="RequestLogger"/>
         <jms:outbound-endpoint queue="NewQueue" connector-ref="Active_MQ" doc:name="JMS" exchange-pattern="request-response"/>
    </flow>


    <flow name="testFlow1" doc:name="testFlow1" initialState="started">
       <jms:inbound-endpoint connector-ref="Active_MQ" address="jms://tcp:NewQueue" doc:name="JMS" exchange-pattern="request-response" disableTemporaryReplyToDestinations="true" responseTimeout="90000"/>
        <jersey:resources doc:name="REST">
            <component class="com.test.services.schema.maindata.v1.Impl.MainDataImpl"/>
        </jersey:resources>
    </flow>
```

Now I want whenever the service is triggered from a rest client the request should first enter into an ActiveMQ queue **NewQueue** in **MainService flow** and in **testFlow1 flow** it will get the request from  **NewQueue** and will execute it ..

Now there are 2 methods in this webservice :-

- The first method is **insertDataOperation** which is triggered from
  rest client as a POST method and it accept the JSON request on it's
  body ..
- The second method is **retrieveDataOperation** which has is
  triggered from rest client as a GET method which has request in the
  url like the following :-
  `http://localhost:8082/getData/retrieve/?id=21` where the value is in
  id ..

Now when ever I trigger the value I get the following exception :-

```
INFO  2014-08-10 20:23:56,622 [[test].connector.http.mule.default.receiver.02] org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Initialising: 'Active_MQ.dispatcher.2028594834'. Object is: EeJmsMessageDispatcher
INFO  2014-08-10 20:23:56,622 [[test].connector.http.mule.default.receiver.02] org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Starting: 'Active_MQ.dispatcher.2028594834'. Object is: EeJmsMessageDispatcher
ERROR 2014-08-10 20:23:56,709 [ActiveMQ Session Task-1] org.mule.exception.DefaultMessagingExceptionStrategy: 
********************************************************************************
Message               : Failed to invoke JerseyResourcesComponent{testFlow1.component.1820680768}. Component that caused exception is: JerseyResourcesComponent{testFlow1.component.1820680768}. Message payload is of type: String
Code                  : MULE_ERROR--2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception stack is:
1. null (java.lang.NullPointerException)
  org.mule.module.jersey.JerseyResourcesComponent:116 (null)
2. Failed to invoke JerseyResourcesComponent{testFlow1.component.1820680768}. Component that caused exception is: JerseyResourcesComponent{testFlow1.component.1820680768}. Message payload is of type: String (org.mule.component.ComponentException)
  org.mule.component.AbstractComponent:144 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/component/ComponentException.html)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace:
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.mule.module.jersey.JerseyResourcesComponent.doInvoke(JerseyResourcesComponent.java:116)
    at org.mule.component.AbstractComponent.invokeInternal(AbstractComponent.java:122)
    at org.mule.component.AbstractComponent.access$000(AbstractComponent.java:57)
    + 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
********************************************************************************

ERROR 2014-08-10 20:23:57,746 [ActiveMQ Session Task-2] org.mule.exception.DefaultMessagingExceptionStrategy: 
********************************************************************************
Message               : "Message with id "ID:ANIRBAN-PC-50216-1407682432183-1:1:6:1:1" has been redelivered 1 times on endpoint "jms://tcp:NewQueue", which exceeds the maxRedelivery setting of 0 on the connector "Active_MQ". Message payload is of type: ActiveMQTextMessage
Code                  : MULE_ERROR--2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception stack is:
1. "Message with id "ID:ANIRBAN-PC-50216-1407682432183-1:1:6:1:1" has been redelivered 1 times on endpoint "jms://tcp:NewQueue", which exceeds the maxRedelivery setting of 0 on the connector "Active_MQ". Message payload is of type: ActiveMQTextMessage (org.mule.transport.jms.redelivery.MessageRedeliveredException)
  org.mule.transport.jms.redelivery.JmsXRedeliveryHandler:81 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/transport/jms/redelivery/MessageRedeliveredException.html)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace:
org.mule.transport.jms.redelivery.MessageRedeliveredException: "Message with id "ID:ANIRBAN-PC-50216-1407682432183-1:1:6:1:1" has been redelivered 1 times on endpoint "jms://tcp:NewQueue", which exceeds the maxRedelivery setting of 0 on the connector "Active_MQ". Message payload is of type: ActiveMQTextMessage
    at org.mule.transport.jms.redelivery.JmsXRedeliveryHandler.handleRedelivery(JmsXRedeliveryHandler.java:81)
    at org.mule.transport.jms.MultiConsumerJmsMessageReceiver$JmsWorker.preProcessMessage(MultiConsumerJmsMessageReceiver.java:512)
    at org.mule.transport.AbstractReceiverWorker$1$1.process(AbstractReceiverWorker.java:117)
    + 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
********************************************************************************
```

Now I guess the request need to be inserted into the ActiveMQ queue `NewQueue` should be String format in case of **insertDataOperation** as the request is on BODY .. and I am not sure for **retrieveDataOperation** which carries value id in url ...

Please let me know how to fix the exception for both the cases ... Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most prominent problem is that you only send the payload of the HTTP request via the JMS endpoint, which is of course not enough for the Jersey to be happy.

You need to serialize the **whole Mule message** to XML (so it's properties are carried over too) ...

```
<xml:object-to-xml-transformer acceptMuleMessage="true" />
```

... then send it over JMS, then deserialize it before the Jersey component.

TBF I don't know if this will work but that's probably the closest to a working solution you will be.

Comment: OHHHH ..Wonderful ... It works David Thanks .. What's the exact reason ?? Why it require to accept the whole Mule message ?? Does it need to accommodate message id and correlation id etc etc ?

Comment: The HTTP endpoint creates a truckload of properties (see: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/HTTP+Transport+Reference#HTTPTransportReference-HTTPProperties), some of which are essential for a REST API to work. That's why you need to carry them across JMS.

Answer (score 0):

So as per David's suggestion need to add :-

```
<mulexml:object-to-xml-transformer acceptMuleMessage="true" doc:name="Object to XML"/>
```

**UPDATED WORKING FLOW :-**

```
<jms:activemq-connector name="Active_MQ" brokerURL="tcp://localhost:61616" validateConnections="true" doc:name="Active MQ"/>

<flow name="MainService" doc:name="MainService">
<http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8082" doc:name="HTTP"/>
<logger message="RequestLog :- #[message.payloadAs(java.lang.String)]" level="INFO" doc:name="RequestLogger"/>
<mulexml:object-to-xml-transformer acceptMuleMessage="true" doc:name="Object to XML"/>
<jms:outbound-endpoint queue="NewQueue" connector-ref="Active_MQ" doc:name="JMS" exchange-pattern="request-response"/>
</flow>

<flow name="testFlow1" doc:name="testFlow1" initialState="started">
 <jms:inbound-endpoint connector-ref="Active_MQ" address="jms://tcp:NewQueue" doc:name="JMS" exchange-pattern="request-response" disableTemporaryReplyToDestinations="true" responseTimeout="90000"/>
 <mulexml:xml-to-object-transformer doc:name="XML to Object"/>
 <jersey:resources doc:name="REST">
   <component class="com.test.services.schema.maindata.v1.Impl.MainDataImpl"/>
 </jersey:resources>
</flow>
```